# Mat-DatePicker - display format dd/mm/yyyy with useUtc: true

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I'm from India (+5:30 Offset) my requirement is to display the date in dd/mm/yyyy format and it should always be utc date otherwise it subtracts the time offset and passes yesterday's date in the http post.

I'm maintaining a common module to import the necessary mat modules in my feature modules. Will it possible to have a fix globally, so that there wont be any change inside my feature modules.

Can someone guide me on this?

Thanks in advance.

MuthuD

Answer (score 1):

You can use Moment JS with Angular Material and since you are using a common module, you can make the change a one place and it would work in your whole application.
This Angular blog specifies the way you can use this.
https://blog.angular.io/taking-advantage-of-the-angular-material-datepicker-237e80fa14b3

It is an inbuilt support in Angular Material library.

```
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [MdDatepickerModule],
    providers: [
        {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter},
        {provide: MD_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS},
   ],
})
```

Comment: This is also somewhat explained on the official docs, for reference: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings

Comment: @Satpal Tanan, Thanks.   Sorry for the delayed response.

I'm not sure what i'm missing, I have created a sample here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datepicker-exploration?file=src/app/app.module.ts

As I mentioned before, I need the date format to be dd/mm/yyyy and the date should be in utc. 

Can you please review and guide me on this.

Comment: Can someone resolved this before, This is still pending at my end. Any help would be appreciated.